# Split a delimited file into multiple files based on the values in one column

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I have a text file that has 6 fields delimited by `~`. I need to write the lines to multiple new files whose names are based on the 5th field in the line, such that all lines with the same 5th field end up in the same file. For example, all lines with `foo` in the 5th field should end up in `Src_foo.txt`.

## Sample input

```
WatchListEntry_20180820_DLY_0.dat~3~NA~USD~AMLCOMP~2018-08-20~
WatchListEntry_20180820_DLY_2.dat~3~NA~USD~CBNABI~2018-08-20~
WatchListEntry_20180820_DLY_99.dat~3~NA~USD~AMLDW~2018-08-20~
BackOfficeTransaction_20180820_DLY_1.dat~5~0~USD~CBNABI~2018-08-
```

## Sample output

### Src_AMLCOMP.txt

```
WatchListEntry_20180820_DLY_0.dat~3~NA~USD~AMLCOMP~2018-08-20
```

### Src_AMLDW.txt

```
WatchListEntry_20180820_DLY_99.dat~3~NA~USD~AMLDW~2018-08-20
```

### Src_CBNABI.txt

```
WatchListEntry_20180820_DLY_2.dat~3~NA~USD~CBNABI~2018-08-20
BackOfficeTransaction_20180820_DLY_1.dat~5~0~USD~CBNABI~2018-08-20
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question on SE Unix & Linux should show some proof of work. This question show none.

Comment: @Chandrakala can you cross check your expected output. `Src_CBNABI.txt:` must have one line

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) first and then learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/467268/edit) and show us what you tried so far.

Answer (score 4):

How far would

```
awk -F"~" '{print >> ("Src_" $5 ".txt")}' file
```

get you? You may need to close the output files if you get near the maximum number of open files allowed.

Comment: can you please elaborate, how it works

Comment: As the fifth field holds the essential part of the target file name, the latter is contructed from it and then used for the redirection of the `print` statement, which by default prints `$0`, the entire input line.

Comment: Is it possible to create the folder in another directory while re-directing

Comment: Certainly. Use `awk`'s `system` call to run `mkdir`.

Comment: sorry for the typo, Is it possible to create the files in another directory while re-directing

Comment: Yes - pass the new directory in an `awk` variable. Or generate on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for i in `cat file.txt`
do
        File=`echo $i | awk -F '~' '{print "Src_"$5".txt"}'`
        echo "$i" >> $File
done
```

- pass the content of `file.txt` line by line to `for` loop.
- extract the 5th field and `Src_` as prefix and `.txt` as the suffix to declare it as filename
- then pass the content to the file.

Comment: [don't read the lines of a file with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)